# how to temporarily configure SSH proxy server

Tags: ssh, networking, git

I'm often in a network that for some silly reason blocks TCP destination port 22. It doesn't seem practical to use a full VPN just to overcome this issue, so I'm sometimes using SSH proxy (via `ProxyCommand`), sometimes a pseudo-VPN using a combination of `ssh -w any:any -p 443` and a couple of local and remote `ip` command lines.

I'm using SSH as the backend for Git so I cannot directly change the `ssh` command line.

What I'm looking for is a clean and nice way to temporarily (e.g. via a simple script or environment variable) to contact Git servers like GitHub and Fedora distgit via a server with SSH accessible via TCP port 443. I don't insist on `ProxyCommand` or `-w` as the methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can store both `ProxyCommand` and `Tunnel` with `TunnelDevice` in your `ssh_config`. Git is respects your `ssh` configuration you define in `~/.ssh/config`.

Additionally, in the Fedora 25 (openssh-7.3, or from [copr](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/jjelen/openssh-latest/)), you can use `Include` directive to modify your configuration using single character in your configuration, something like:

```
# ~/.ssh/config
#Include ~/.ssh/config_proxy
Host github.com
  # some standard configuration
```

---

```
# ~/.ssh/config_proxy
Host github.com
  ProxyCommand something
```

You can certainly to script this change with simple `sed`, if you wish.

Comment: So your interpretation of the word *temporarily* is to temporarily modify the permanent configuration. Fair enough. But I really hoped for something that will not have permanent side effects if I fail to switch it back.

Comment: (Un)fortunately, `ssh` does not react on (almost any) environment variables, which makes the results quire reproducible. Though you can pass the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` env. var to git, where you can also add `ssh -F ~/.ssh/config_proxy`, if it is what you want.

Comment: I have just tried `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F ~/.ssh/config.proxy" git ...` and it works for more or less. But I realized I cannot set ProxyCommand globally as I'm currently using `ProxyCommand ssh my-ssh-server -p 443 nc github.com 22`, which I can only use for github. I would instead like to gobally tunnel all Git/SSH connections through the chosen SSH server. I didn't think about that before so it's not included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

With reasonably recent versions of the OpenSSH client, you can put conditional settings in your `.ssh/config`. So you can set the `ProxyCommand` line inside a conditional stanza. Besides conditions based on the target which aren't useful here, you can have a condition that consists of running an external command. Use a command to detect whether you're in the network where the proxy is needed, e.g. by checking your DHCP lease.

```
Match exec "awk /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases '$2 == \"domain-name-servers\" {nsip=$3} END {exit(nsip == \"192.0\.2\.1\")}'"
    ProxyCommand …
```