# Hardwire jump host in ssh_config

Tags: centos, ssh, proxy, openssh

When I do `ssh myuser@technicaluser@targethost@jumphost` this works fine and I can connect to `targethost` without having to enter the password of `technicaluser`, ssh only asks for the password of `myuser`.

I tried to "hardwire" the technicaluser and jumphost in my ssh_config because I don`t want to enter this any time I use ssh and because this will make my life easier when using git and ansible.

But regardless of which approach I use ssh always asks for the password of the `technicaluser` (and I do not know that password due to security concerns)

I modified my ~/.ssh/config like this ...

```
Include ~/.ssh/config_proxy
```

and created a config_proxy file:

```
Host targethost
  ProxyJump technicaluser@jumphost
```

I took this from the [cookbook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts).
The answer in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302991/how-to-temporarily-configure-ssh-proxy-server) didn't work for me either.

There are no other entries than these in my user ssh config, /etc/ssh/ssh_config contains these lines which I consider standard for a fresh CentOS install:

```
Host *
  GSSAPIAuthentication yes
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
  SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
  SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
  SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
  SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

This is the log of a *failed* attempt up to the point where I am being asked to enter the password:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myuser/.ssh/config
debug3: /home/myuser/.ssh/config line 1: Including file /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy
debug1: /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy line 1: Applying options for targethost
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -l technicaluser -p 22 -vvv -W %h:%p jumphost
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l technicaluser -p 22 -vvv -W targethost:22 jumphost
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1001
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myuser/.ssh/config
debug3: /home/myuser/.ssh/config line 1: Including file /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy
debug1: /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy line 1: Applying options for targethost
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -l technicaluser -p 22 -vvv -W %h:%p jumphost
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l technicaluser -p 22 -vvv -W targethost:22 jumphost
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1001
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This is the log for a **successful** connection using the syntax with the multiple at signs:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myuser/.ssh/config
debug3: /home/myuser/.ssh/config line 1: Including file /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myuser/.ssh/config_proxy
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "jumphost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to jumphost [192.168.171.222] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to jumphost:22 as 'myuser@technicaluser@targethost'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from jumphost
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:iiydeRoSRwCeGxkTxAbvU0xOdI5DXhYzFpgC4+8446U
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from jumphost
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.171.222
debug1: Host 'jumphost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to jumphost ([192.168.171.222]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED
debug3: Ignored env SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env HTTP_PROXY
debug3: Ignored env HTTPS_PROXY
debug3: Ignored env http_proxy
debug3: Ignored env https_proxy
debug3: Ignored env ZSH
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env P
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Transferred: sent 2436, received 5068 bytes, in 9.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 260.9, received 542.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: you should at least add some debug logs from an ssh connection attempt

Comment: I'm sorry, I scanned briefly and none of the several recipes in your linked page seem to match the "user@user@host@host" syntax you're using successfully? Please give relevant excerpts of your `.ssh/config`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz my ssh config was empty until I added the lines you can see in the post. All there is are the entries in /etc/ssh/ssh_config which seem to be the standard values of a fresh CentOS install. I will add them to my post.

Comment: @DiegoRoccia I added the log of a failed _and_ a successfull attempt. I tried to compare them but didn't find relevant differences.